# How do I access classes in App_Code using an ObjectDataSource?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to access my classes using an ObjectDataSource but unfortunately my classes aren't showing up in the dropdownlist.

Browsing Stackoverflow, I came across several solutions which none of them worked for me. This is what I tried (I cleaned and rebuild my solution after all of these):

- Changing the build action from content to compile
- Moving my classes out of the `App_Code` folder
- Creating a new fresh class outside `App_Code`
- Changed namespace of my classes from `ProjectName.App_Code` to `ProjectName`
- Added Using `ProjectName.App_Code;` to the code behind in my aspx file

At this point, I really don't know what I could try. Here's what a typical class inside `App_Code` looks like:

[The class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pjxWi.png)

[Location in project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zlJfH.png)

Comment: I would suggest and or recommend that you do a `C# MSDN namespace` search sounds like this is the issue also understand how to create and or change the default namespace from the project properties

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution to my problem. Turns out I can choose between two type of classes and I was choosing the wrong one.

[Here's the class I should have been using](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImqsD.png)

[Here's the class I was using previously](https://i.stack.imgur.com/04ssK.png)